# Change the background

Tags: css

how to change the background of the  css? i have to change the url, but the image doesn't change instantly

please help me ^.^ thankyou

```
.masthead { 
  min-height: 30rem;
  position: relative;  
  display: table;  
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%), url("../img/bg-masthead.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: it might take a browser a bit of time to download the image....

Comment: clear your browser cache...

Comment: Hit `Ctrl + F5` to force-refresh and see if that changes your background. Otherwise, check and make sure `../img/bg-masthead.jpg` is the image you updated.

Comment: thankyou very much. its trully working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to do a hard reload in order to get the Image to load. If that doesn't work just go ahead and clear your cached data. Also, You can always use an incognito window to not have to mess with your chase every time.